# How to limit the search result to once in REGEX in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
const EXPECTEDSELLERID = res.data.match(
    /data\-expected\-seller\-id=([\s\S]*?)\ /g
  );

/*

Returns below result:
[
  'data-expected-seller-id=2554543745 ',
  'data-expected-seller-id=2554543745 '
]

 */
```

The above regex returns the searched string twice, because it is available twice in the original string.

Is there any way to return it only once?

Comment: Remove the `g` flag and the capturing group if you do not need to access the value captured.

Comment: then it returns complete string(which is a HTML source code) along with the results in an array, plus `groups: undefined`

Comment: You are not using it right, `const EXPECTEDSELLERID = res.data.match(/data-expected-seller-id=(\S+)/)[0]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I got it now, and it's working. I am not very efficient in regex and still learning. Thanks for your prompt help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const EXPECTEDSELLERID = res.data.match.match(
    /\b(data\-expected\-seller\-id=([\s\S]*?))\ \b/g
  );

/* console.log(EXPECTEDSELLERID ) // ["data-expected-seller-id=2554543745 "] */
```